# Python while loop for optimization

Tags: python, pytorch

Instead of using for-loop, which is required to set # of iterations in advance. However, in practice, we often do not know how many iterations are needed to reach the optimal. I would like to use `while loop` but my code seems to be incorrect (it stops in the 1st iteration). The goal is to stop iterating when **|new_loss - loss| < tolerance**

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

i = 1                    # iteration
tolerance = 0.001        # tolerance 

while True:
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data)
    loss = F.nll_loss(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])         #old_loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    new_loss = F.nll_loss(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])     #new_loss
    print(f"epoch: {i} & loss: {new_loss}")
    if torch.abs(new_loss-loss) < tolerance:
        break
    else:
        i += 1

epoch: 1 & loss: 1.9830527305603027
```

For loop approach

```
model.train()
for epoch in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data)
    loss = F.nll_loss(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])
    print(f"epoch:{epoch} & loss = {loss}")
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

epoch:997 & loss = 0.8235331773757935
epoch:998 & loss = 0.7414383888244629
epoch:999 & loss = 0.8728649616241455
```

The for loop and while loop give me two different results. Any suggestion?

Comment: obviously `torch.abs(new_loss-loss)` is less than your tolerance on the first pass...

Comment: I also have tried for loop but the results are significantly different from the while loop. I can't tell which part causes this difference.

Comment: It's likely that either your ```data``` object or your ```out``` object does not get updated in-between the ```F.nll_loss()``` calls.  Therefore, the result is equal, and the diff is less than tolerance.  Also, your ```model.train()``` sits outside the loop in your working code, and not in your failing code.  It has to be one of those issues.

Comment: Instead of using if and else, you could just write `while torch.abs(new_loss-loss) >= tolerance:`

Comment: @Rob, I also have tried this approach but it does not work either. Still thanks anyway!!

Comment: In while loop for `new_loss` you're using `out` computed before optimizer step, hence  `new_loss == loss`.

Comment: @draw, thank you so much. Yes. this is the problem, which I did not catch. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, figure it out

```
i = 1                     # iteration
tolerance = 0.001         # tolerance 
while True:
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    out = model(data)                                                           # old model parameters
    loss = F.nll_loss(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])            # old_loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    new_out = model(data)                                                        # model parameters
    new_loss = F.nll_loss(new_out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])     # new_loss
    print(f"epoch: {i} & loss: {new_loss}")
    if torch.abs(new_loss-loss) < tolerance:
        break
    else:
        i += 1

epoch: 76 & loss: 1.3499773740768433
epoch: 77 & loss: 1.3079249858856201
epoch: 78 & loss: 1.3511285781860352
epoch: 79 & loss: 1.3647903203964233
```

Need to calculate a new loss with new model (parameter estimates).